# Newb Question Involving Engine Yard

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, virtualhost

Okay, so maybe this sounds really dumb, but I'm not really a server guy. I write code.

Anyways, trying to configure two Rails apps on a solo instance on Engine Yard. I have two domains bought through GoDaddy and I have the A records setup to the addresses that I want. But I really have no idea what to do when it comes to setting up Apache/Passenger (or Nginx) to run the two apps under the same IP. I've done this on a Redhat system before where I control all the server structure, but I'm not really sure what's going on in Engineyard.

Anyone have experience with this can help me out?

(Posted from StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've helped someone set up a Rails Yard thing once, a few months ago.  Basically, it just means you have to add each application and use a unique domain name for each one.

I mostly helped as a back-seat driver, but looking through their FAQ is also a good place to start.

FWIW, we decided not to use Engine Yard, but instead stick to hosting on a server we had full control over.  It just makes things... simpler.

Comment: i just need to get ahold of a machine that I can commandeer for this purpose... I agree though, definitely like that option much better than what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post on the Engine Yard community site helpful:

https://cloud-support.engineyard.com/faqs/using-engine-yard-cloud/configuring-multiple-domain-names-on-one-environment